# Need suggestions to attach JavaScript function to SharePoint search button click

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, search, search-results

I need to attached custom JavaScript function to SharePoint 2013 search button click.
When user enter some text in search box and click search button or click "Enter" key, my custom JavaScript should also need to execute.

I can see the URL changes whenever user make a new query but it is not loading the entire page.

I added CEWP and added following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Log by search button click");
});
```

It is not writing the in to console log on search button click.
It only writes when I reload the page manually..

Please suggest me how to make my custom function execute on every user search.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing on click?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add an eventlistner.

If you have a pre-made function you want to call simply call it in the body of the eventlistener.

The below uses Jquery but normal JS works fine as well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#ButtonID").on('click', function () {
        logIt();
     });
 });

function logIt()
{
   console.log("Log by search button click");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Roland.. I tried your code but it still not executing the function.. may be because of partial page load.. I am not sure..   Any suggestions

Comment: Are you getting any warnings/errors from the code? Also what search button are you referring to (the magnifying glass?)?